# Getting result By Linq GroupBy expression in lambda-exp

Tags: c#, linq

```
using MeetingCases;

List<int> ourList = new List<int> { 7, 8, 7, 5, 6, 5, 5, 7, 1, 3, 7, 3, 1, 4 };
var resultus = ourList.Skip(3).Take(4).Sum();
var yay = ourList.GroupBy(key =>
{
    resultus += key;
    return key;
}).Select(z => new {z.Key, resultus });
Console.WriteLine($"Result is {resultus}");
yay.ToList();

Console.WriteLine($"Result is {resultus}");
```

Could you please explain why in the first CW we get resultus as 21 however after **yay.ToList();**
get 90.

Thank you

Comment: Because `resultus = 21`, then you use `resultus += key` for each of the items in `ourList` (their sum is 69) so the final result is 90 as expected. You get different result after `ToList()` because you use `.Select` which returns an IEnumerable, which is _"executed"_ when you force it to be processed.

Comment: Apparently you expected `ourList.Skip(3).Take(4).Sum()` to have deferred execution. It hasn't. `Sum` is one of the LINQ operators that force execution.

Comment: My main concern is why resultus becomes equal to 90 after yay.ToList()

Comment: Because `.Sum()` makes the operation executed immediately. `.Select()` has deferred execution, meaning that the operation gets executed when you call `.ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a *Linq* for `yay` with a side effect: when selecting `kay` you *modify* `resultus` in the process:

```
    resultus += key;
```

When you *materialize* `yay` the *side effect* shows itself:

```
List<int> ourList = new List<int> { 
  7, 8, 7, 5, 6, 5, 5, 7, 1, 3, 7, 3, 1, 4 
};

// So you sum 4 values from ourList and got 5 + 6 + 5 + 5 = 21
var resultus = ourList.Skip(3).Take(4).Sum();

// Note, that Linq is lazy: the query below is just declaration for now
// Nothing is performed 
var yay = ourList.GroupBy(key =>
{
    // When grouping you are going to items to resultus (which is 21)
    resultus += key; // <- you may want to drop this line
    return key;
}).Select(z => new {z.Key, resultus });

// Since query abouve is not materialized, resultus is not changed, it's 21
Console.WriteLine($"Result is {resultus}");

// You materialize the query above (yay), to do it 
// Linq is perfomed and several keys (7, 8, ..., 3, 1, 4) are added to resultus
// 21 + (7 + 8 + 7 + ... + 1 + 4) = 90
yay.ToList();

// From now on resultus is 90
```